# Issue Updating Data Table Values with Modal in Next.js/Supabase

Tags: reactjs, typescript, next.js, supabase

I'm encountering an issue with updating values in a data table that displays users and specific information about them from a database. I've implemented an edit feature using a modal that prefills with the current information. However, when I attempt to update the user details through the modal, no changes are reflected in the data table.

Modal Component:

```
interface EditMembersProps {
  members: Members;
}

const EditMembers: React.FC<EditMembersProps> = ({ members }) => {
  const [showModal, setShowModal] = useState(false);
  const [formData, setFormData] = useState({
    first_name: members?.first_name,
    last_name: members?.last_name,
    age: members?.age,
    gender: members?.gender,
    weight_class: members?.weight_class,
    status: members?.status,
    open: members?.open,
  });

  const handleChange = (e: any) => {
    setFormData({
      ...formData,
      [e.target.name]: e.target.value,
    });
  };

  return (
    <div>
      <button onClick={() => setShowModal(true)}>Edit</button>
      {showModal && (
        <div className="fixed inset-0 bg-gray-800 bg-opacity-75 flex justify-center items-center px-4">
          <div className="modal-content bg-gray-900 p-6 rounded-lg w-full max-w-md">
            <span
              className="close text-white text-xl leading-none hover:text-gray-300 cursor-pointer float-right"
              onClick={() => setShowModal(false)}
            >
              &times;
            </span>
            <form action={UpdateMembers} className="mt-4">
              <input type="hidden" name="id" value={members.id} />
              <div className="mb-4">
                <label
                  htmlFor="first_name"
                  className="block text-gray-300 mb-2"
                >
                  First Name
                </label>
                <input
                  type="text"
                  id="first_name"
                  name="first_name"
                  value={formData.first_name}
                  onChange={handleChange}
                  className="w-full p-2 rounded bg-gray-800 text-white border border-gray-700 focus:border-blue-500"
                />
              </div>

{* more of the code above*}

                <button
                type="submit"
                className="w-full bg-blue-500 hover:bg-blue-700 text-white font-bold py-2 px-4 rounded"
              >
                Update Member
              </button>
            </form>
```

UpdateMembers:

```
export async function UpdateMembers(
  id?: any,
  first_name?: string,
  last_name?: string,
  weight_class?: string,
  age?: number,
  gender?: string,
  open?: string,
  status?: string
) {
  const supabase = await createSupabaseServerClient(); 

  return await supabase
    .from("Members")
    .update({first_name, last_name, weight_class, age, gender, open, status})
    .match({ id });
}
```

Columns:

> ```
> export const columns: ColumnDef<Members>[] = [
>   {
>     accessorKey: "first_name",
>     header: ({ column }) => {
>       return (
>         <Button
>           variant="ghost"
>           onClick={() => column.toggleSorting(column.getIsSorted() === "asc")}
>         >
>           First
>           <ArrowUpDown className="ml-2 h-4 w-4" />
>         </Button>
>       );
>     },
>   },
> {* more of the same code*}, 
> {
>     id: "edit",
>     cell: ({ row }) => {
>       const member = row.original;
>
>       return (
>         <DropdownMenu>
>           <EditMembers members={member} />
>         </DropdownMenu>
>       );
>     },
>   },
> ```

Checked the network requests in the browser's developer tools to ensure the update request is being sent but nothing sent.  Attempted to use the **`onSubmit`** event handler in the modal's form to capture and handle the submission, but the issue persists.